# Can't Add Constraints to Button Programatically - Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, nslayoutconstraint

I have a subView named `loginView` and within that a few other elements, namely `loginButton` and `loginUsername`

I am trying to programatically add a Facebook login button that has constraints relative to `loginButton`, `loginView` and `loginUsername`

Here is my code

```
self.loginView.addSubview(facebookLoginButton)

let facebookLoginButtonTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
      item: facebookLoginButton, 
      attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 
      relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
      toItem: loginButton, 
      attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 
      multiplier: 1, 
      constant: 8
)

let facebookLoginButtonLeadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
      item: facebookLoginButton, 
      attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 
      relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
      toItem: loginView, 
      attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 
      multiplier: 1, 
      constant: 8
)

let facebookLoginButtonWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
      item: facebookLoginButton, 
      attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 
      relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
      toItem: loginUsername, 
      attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 
      multiplier: 1, 
      constant: 0
)

self.loginView.addConstraints([
      facebookLoginButtonTopConstraint, 
      facebookLoginButtonLeadingConstraint
])
self.facebookLoginButton.addConstraint(facebookLoginButtonWidthConstraint)
```

This code is going in my viewDidLoad method. The error I'm getting is:

The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: 
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: add `facebookLoginButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` first

Comment: Adding this before all of my above code (still in the viewDidLoad method) failed and still produced the same error. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

The error says all. You need to prepare all views to hierarchy before adding constraints. Check that all four views are added to view hierarchy before adding constraints (didn't you forget `addSubvew` for some view?). **Do not move this code to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method, this is wrong hint!** Because you don't want to add constraints multiple times. Also, you should add `facebookLoginButtonWidthConstraint` to view that owns both (`loginView`?), `facebookLoginButton` and `loginUsername`, since this is shared constraint